# Angular Material stranger render behavior

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm using the latest version of Angular and Angular Material. I'm having issues with my components. The page Load like this:
[Before de click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PLUt.jpg)
And the content just appear when I click on the menu.
[After clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgADC.jpg)
I already tried to uninstall and install all the meterial stuff. And this issue continues. I have a separate module to import and export all the material components. Here is the code of the component that is using the material tags:

profile.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import {AuthService} from "../../services/auth.service";
import {User} from "../../model/model.user";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { Expense } from '../../model/model.expense';
import { ReceiptService } from "../../services/receipt.service";
import { ExpenseService } from './../../services/expense.service';
import { Receipt } from './../../model/model.receipt';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  totalReceita = 0;
  totalDespesa = 0;
  receipts = []
  expenses = []
  currentUser: User;
  constructor(public authService: AuthService, public router: Router, public receiptService: ReceiptService,  public expenseService: ExpenseService) {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.receiptService.getReceipts(this.currentUser.id).subscribe(
      data => {

        console.log(data)
        this.receipts = this.retiraArrayRec(data);
        this.somaTudoRec();
      }
      );
      this.expenseService.getExpenses(this.currentUser.id).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.expenses =this.retiraArrayDesp(data);
          this.somaTudoDes();
        }
        );
        console.log(this.receipts)
  }
  retiraArrayRec(data){
    let lista = []
    data.forEach(element => {
      let receita : Receipt = new Receipt;
      receita.name = element[0];
      receita.value = element[1]
      lista.push(receita);
    });
    return lista;
  }
  retiraArrayDesp(data){
    let lista = []
    data.forEach(element => {
      let despesa : Expense = new Expense;
      despesa.name = element[0];
      despesa.value = element[1]
      lista.push(despesa);
    });
    return lista;
  }

  somaTudoRec(){
    this.receipts.forEach(element => {
     this.totalReceita += element.value;
    });
  }
  somaTudoDes(){
    this.expenses.forEach(element => {
     this.totalDespesa += element.value;
    });
  }


// login out from the app
  logOut() {
    this.authService.logOut()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        },
        error => {

        });
  }
```

}

profile.component.html

```
    <mat-sidenav-container fullscreen class="menu-container">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active-list-item">
                <h2 matLine>Home</h2>
                <mat-icon matListIcon>home</mat-icon>
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink="/account" routerLinkActive="active-list-item">
                <h2 matLine>Receitas</h2>
                <mat-icon matListIcon>local_atm</mat-icon>
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink="/settings" routerLinkActive="active-list-item">
                <h2 matLine>Despesas</h2>
                <mat-icon matListIcon>show_chart</mat-icon>
            </a>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink="/settings" routerLinkActive="active-list-item">
                <h2 matLine>Notificações</h2>
                <mat-icon matListIcon>notification_important</mat-icon>
            </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content fxFlexFill>
        <mat-toolbar>
                <button class="hamburger mat-button" mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
                  <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
                  <span>Menu</span>
                </button>

                <span>Bem vindo ao CPF, Pedro</span>

                <button mat-icon-button [mat-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
                  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
                </button>
              </mat-toolbar>
              <mat-menu x-position="before" #menu="matMenu">
                <button mat-menu-item>
                  <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
                  <span>Perfil</span>
                </button>
                <button mat-menu-item>
                  <mat-icon>money_off</mat-icon>
                  <span>Sair</span>
                </button>
              </mat-menu>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

profile.component.css

```
    mat-toolbar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #00b4db, #0083b0);
  color: #fff;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

  span {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 700;
  }

  .hamburger {
      height: 100%;
      font-size: 18px;
  }


.mat-sidenav-container {
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

  .mat-sidenav {
      flex: 0 1 auto;
  }
  .menu-spacer {
      flex: 1;
  }

  .mat-list-item-content {
      padding: 0 25px;
  }


.menu-container {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Could you create a _[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_ (such as a StackBlitz) so that we could help you?

Comment: Looks like it may be something to do with a broken theme. See https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme on how to use a prebuilt theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please consider that you need to insert style into the project:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

If it did not solve the problem, I guess it's because you are using another font and also added !important for the font, please try to add the code below in your style.css (or style.scss) which is the general/public CSS file which effects on your whole project:

```
mat-icon{
  font-family: 'Material Icons' !important;
}
```